# Filter only few element of groups after pandas groupby

Tags: python, r, pandas, filter

I was learning the book "R for Data Science" by Hadly and trying to
replicate the codes in pandas.

I encountered this problem:
I have to create a new column of rank based on the delayed time of
the flights and filter only min and max values of them.

R-code:

```r
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

# remove nans
not_cancelled = flights %>% 
    filter( !is.na(dep_delay), !is.na(arr_delay))

# create new column of rank based on dep_time for each day.
df = not_cancelled %>%  
    group_by(year,month,day) %>%  
    mutate(r = min_rank(desc(dep_time))) %>%  
    filter(r %in% range(r)) %>%  # filter only first and last value
    select(year,month,day,dep_delay,arr_delay,r)

dim(df)
head(df,10)
```

This gives:

```
m=month d =day dl = dep_delay ad = arr_delay r =r
    year    m   d   dl  ad  r
    2013    1   1    2  11  831
    2013    1   1   -3  -12 1
    2013    1   2   43  36  928
    2013    1   2   -5  -24 1
    2013    1   3   33  22  900
    2013    1   3   -10 -11 1
    2013    1   4   26  23  908
    2013    1   4   -1  -8  1 
    2013    1   4   -1  -9  1 # Behold! january 4 has 3 rows!!
    2013    1   5   15  18  717
```

I am trying to replicate this in pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/bhishanpdl/Datasets/blob/master/nycflights13.csv?raw=true')
# print(df.shape)
# print(df.iloc[:5,:5])

not_cancelled = df.dropna(subset=['dep_delay','arr_delay'])

df['r'] = not_cancelled.groupby(['year','month','day'])['dep_time']\
    .rank('min',ascending=False)

g = df.groupby(['year','month','day'])['r']
g = g.agg([min,max]).reset_index()

f = g.head()
print(f)
```

Python output:

```
(336776, 19)
   year  month  day  min    max
0  2013      1    1  1.0  831.0
1  2013      1    2  1.0  928.0
2  2013      1    3  1.0  900.0
3  2013      1    4  1.0  908.0
4  2013      1    5  1.0  717.0
```

This is not quite right. How to do the correct thing?

Help is appreciated. Hail Pandas!

Comment: you could add your result from `pandas`

Comment: how big is this file csv ? You should create small file so we could run it fast.

Comment: @furas, this is not big, it takes few seconds to read data. Updated the question as requested.

Comment: Format your dataframe so the R output looks correct, now its hard to see which values belong to which column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct output , you just need reshape your output

Method 1 `stack`

```
g = df.groupby(['year','month','day'])['r']
g = g.agg([min,max]).stack()
g=g.reset_index(level=[0,1,2])
```

Method 2 `melt`

```
g=df.groupby(['year','month','day'])['r'].agg([min,max])
g.reset_index().melt(['year','month','day'])
```

---

Update

```
g = df.groupby(['year','month','day'])['r']
g_max = g.transform('max')
g_min = g.transform('min')
yourdf=df.loc[(df.r==g_max)|(df.r==g_min),['year','month','day','r']]
```

Comment: This is almost correct, Look at the date for 2013 January 4, there are 3 values: max is 908 and two mins 1.

Comment: Then your problem will be using transform check the update

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly. Thaks a lot. May Jon Snow fight brave tonight!

Answer (score 1):

I created two ranks to have rank 1 for max value and rank 1 for min value.

And then I can get rows which have rank 1 for max or min.

But this gives me two columns - one for `r_max` and one for `r_min`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/bhishanpdl/Datasets/blob/master/nycflights13.csv?raw=true')
# print(df.shape)
# print(df.iloc[:5,:5])

not_cancelled = df.dropna(subset=['dep_delay','arr_delay'])

gr = not_cancelled.groupby(['year','month','day'])

df['r_min'] = gr['dep_time'].rank('min', ascending=False)
df['r_max'] = gr['dep_time'].rank('max', ascending=True)

result = df[(df['r_min'] == 1) | (df['r_max'] == 1)]

print(result[['year','month','day','dep_delay','arr_delay','r_min', 'r_max']].head(10))
```

Result - with three rows for `january 4`

```
      year  month  day  dep_delay  arr_delay  r_min  r_max
0     2013      1    1        2.0       11.0  831.0    1.0
837   2013      1    1       -3.0      -12.0    1.0  831.0
842   2013      1    2       43.0       36.0  928.0    1.0
1776  2013      1    2       -5.0      -24.0    1.0  928.0
1785  2013      1    3       33.0       22.0  900.0    1.0
2688  2013      1    3      -10.0      -11.0    1.0  900.0
2699  2013      1    4       26.0       23.0  908.0    1.0
3606  2013      1    4       -1.0       -8.0    1.0  908.0
3607  2013      1    4       -1.0       -9.0    1.0  908.0
3614  2013      1    5       15.0       18.0  717.0    1.0
```

Comment: great effort but quite not solves the question, look at output for january 4, it should have 3 rows, as given in question.

Comment: try now with `head(10)` ? I see three rows for `january 4` - I replaced  `ascending=False` with `ascending=True` for `max` and `min`

Comment: Yup, perfecto! Works as expected. Thanks again.